# Accessing wireguard VPN endpoint works from WSL2 with mirrored but not from Windows 11 host

Tags: vpn, wsl2, windows-firewall, wireguard

I am using `networkingMode=mirrored` in WSL2 with a couple of wireguard VPNs on the host Windows. 2 wireguard connections (both on `wg0`) go to two different servers for different sets of `10.x` networks (accessing `kilo` instances - wireguard inside kubernetes) and one goes to another wireguard server (`wg1`) for the default network (`0.0.0.0/0`). The wireguard client is only running on the Windows host, not inside WSL2.

I can access everything fine from WSL (Ubuntu) - I can use `kubectl`, `ssh` going to an endpoint in the 10.x (`wg0`) range and I can access anything via the default connection that goes over the VPN (e.g, google, etc.). From the Windows host I can access anything over the default (`wg1`) but I get blocked for everything on the `10.x` (`wg0`).

I tried completely deactivating the Windows firewall, adding `wg0` to the "private" zone, adding rules for particular ports (e.g, `6443`) but nothing seems to work.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

For some strange reason having `0.0.0.0/0` in the `AllowedIPs` for `wg1` was causing an issue for access from the host but not the `wsl2` guest. Adding all those except for the private networks on `wg1` ([thanks to the calculator here](https://www.procustodibus.com/blog/2021/03/wireguard-allowedips-calculator/)) now works for both Win and WSL2.

```
AllowedIPs = 0.0.0.0/5, 8.0.0.0/7, 11.0.0.0/8, 12.0.0.0/6, 16.0.0.0/4, 32.0.0.0/3, 64.0.0.0/2, 128.0.0.0/3, 160.0.0.0/5, 168.0.0.0/6, 172.0.0.0/12, 172.32.0.0/11, 172.64.0.0/10, 172.128.0.0/9, 173.0.0.0/8, 174.0.0.0/7, 176.0.0.0/4, 192.0.0.0/9, 192.128.0.0/11, 192.160.0.0/13, 192.169.0.0/16, 192.170.0.0/15, 192.172.0.0/14, 192.176.0.0/12, 192.192.0.0/10, 193.0.0.0/8, 194.0.0.0/7, 196.0.0.0/6, 200.0.0.0/5, 208.0.0.0/4, 224.0.0.0/3
```